# Transforming points from one coordinate to another

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra

I have data points in a 2D coordinate space that I want to linearly transform to another coordinate space. The image below will make things a little clear.

[image]

The data points I have are in the gray coordinate space (left-top corner A is the x=0,y=0 point). I want to transform all points to the pink coordinate system, for which B is its x=0,y=0 point.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759238/calculate-transformation-which-is-needed-to-transform-a-rectangle-into-its-persp/44761956#44761956

Answer (score 1):

This is not a linear transformation.

Define this "coordinate system" as a convex quad, as follows:

[image]

The vertex coordinates are in parameter space `u, v`. Interpolating along one direction and then the other gives a general point:

[image]

This is *bi-linear* in parameters `u, v`. It only becomes linear if `A + D - B - C = 0`, i.e. the quad is a parallelogram.

---

Transforming between such coordinate systems:

1. Assume (required) that these `ABCD` vertices are embedded in a "global" Cartesian space
2. Convert from the parameter space of the first system to the global space using interpolation as above
3. Convert back to the parameter space by inverting the above equation, solving a pair of simultaneous equations:

   [image]

   Solutions for `u, v`:

   - 1 for a parallelogram (`G = 0`)
   - 2 for a general convex quad, since the coordinate lines (gray) cross a singularity in each direction
   - 0 for a concave quad (complex solutions)

Comment: Nice. I like your answer @meowgoesthedog